# AVD launches with different text and icon sizes

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I have started android development just a month back, so still a newbie. My problem is that my AVD sometimes starts with different icon sizes in the emulator, i.e. the different apps' icons sometimes appear bigger/smaller. Same goes with the text size. This applies to all the applications in the AVD app list(including standard ones like gallery for example), and also the start screen text size. Basically it's system wide and it happens completely randomly(at random AVD launches)!
So help me out. Is there something to do with emulator starting parameters?
Almost forgot - using windows 7 32-bit, eclipse, and SDK 2.3.3
First three images for normal size

[image: Screenshots for normal size]
[image]
[image: image description here]
The images for bigger size below
[image] [image: home screen big][image: menu screen big]
[image: message big]

Comment: this question is related or probably the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698904/android-emulator-boots-with-different-resolution

Comment: The same problem here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613302/small-font-size-in-android-emulator

Comment: Could we get a screenshot of standard vs what your say is 'bigger' ?

Comment: @Blundell Ive put both types of screenshots, please see and lemme know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should should refer to the pixel density. Be sure they stay the same in the emulator settings. If you vary your resolution they might change.

Good introduction: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

EDIT:
Okay, this happens sometimes pure randomly. Close the emulator and restart it. If it still occurs, edit the emulator, leave everything as it is and click on edit.
Should solve the problem.

Comment: Hey, thanks. But i've never varied the resolution and i'll go through the introduction.